# Plots.vline! function is not recognized in new Plots version

Tags: julia, plots.jl, vline

Has Plots changed something about vline(!)? Today in the newly installed machine I tried:

```
begin
    pyplot()
    Plots.plot([57,89])
    Plots.vline!([1.25])
end
```

and got the error quoted at the bottom. The new Plots is v"1.20.0" while on the v"1.19.3" machine it worked fine.

> MethodError: no method matching Val{:vline}

Comment: I just tried with Julia 1.6.2, Plots 1.20.0 and PyPlot 2.9.0 and it worked first try

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me on Plots v1.21.3, with PyPlot v2.9.0:

[image]